# combine value according to date in list

Tags: python, list

I need to make unique list accoding to date. I got unique date list but unable to get sum of unique value in list.

```
enter code here

 print('date 1',uniq_pos_date_list)
 print('values1',amount_list)
 print('date 2', uniq_inv_date_list)
 print('values2', inv_margin_list)
 print('date1+date2 make unique date',srt_uniq_pos_inv_dt)
 print('need help, sum of values 2 according to date')

  date 1 ['2020-01-04', '2020-01-05', '2020-01-06', '2020-01-07']
  values1 [22.6911, 45.88549999999999, 34.0231, 8.52]
  date 2 ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-06', '2020-01-07']
  values2 [0, 34, 4136, -16]
  date1+date2 get unique date 
  ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-04', '2020-01-05', '2020-01-06', '2020-01-07']
```

need help, sum of values 2 according to date
requred list
output should be [0, 56.6911, 45.88, 4136,-7.52]

Comment: At the moment, those date's aren't dates, they are strings. Perhaps you can get the datetime module to work in your advantage.

Comment: yes, these are dates strings i want to make a unique union list with sum of values. following solution is working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 dict1 = {'2020-01-01': 0, '2020-01-04': 22}
 dict2 = {'2020-01-04': 100,'2020-01-05': 20} 
 dic = {} 

 for k1 in dict1.keys():
   if k1 in dict2:
     dict1[k1] = dict1[k1] + dict2[k1]
 # save in new dict
   dic.update(dict1)
 # drop duplicates in dict2
   dict2.pop(k1)
 # add dict2

   dic.update(dict2)
 print(dic)
 #result you will get I hope this method resolve your problem :) glad to help
 # {'2020-01-01': 0, '2020-01-04': 122, '2020-01-05': 20}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer isn't useful in its present form. Could you please format it correctly. There is a [Markdown Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) document to help you.

Comment: I think now it proper formate. Thank to identify :)